# Cascading Dropdowns SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, powerapp

I replicated the example from [Cascading Dropdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/dependent-drop-down-lists) on my SP Dev site.  Created a Locations list with Location and Dept.

Leaving Powerapps and Publishing I then try to create a New Item in my list.  I select the location and the Dept list populates with the correct Depts for that location.  Testing in PowerApps works too btw.

What happens next has me stumped though.  When I save it I'm only getting the Location in my list but not the Dept.

[image]

Here's a screen shot of my Dept settings in PowerApps.  I'm assuming the Location settings are correct. 
[image]

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There were some errors listed at the bottom of that link which I did look into but no luck getting the results I wanted.

Comment: Click on the departments datacard (Outer box of dept dropdown) and on right side properties, click on advanced and post a screenshot of what you see in this property -> Update